# Checking for which of my COM ports are open and usable

Tags: c++

I am quite new to COM port programming and am currently at the basics right now, looking for advice. For checking for COM ports, am I correct in using CreateFile() func? and for checking which of my COM ports are open, is the only way to call this function on each of the COM Ports?

Also is there anything I should keep in mind while going forward? Right now I am just at the basics and appreciate any help. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is my code so far but the COM ports 1-10 are failing or I'm doing something wrong.

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){

    std::string com = "\\\\.\\COM";
    std::string portname;
    HANDLE hCom;

    for( int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::stringstream sstm;
        std::cout << "Trying "<< i<<"\n";
        sstm << com << i;
        portname = sstm.str();
        TCHAR *szPort = (TCHAR*)(portname.c_str());

        hCom = CreateFile(szPort,
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                        0, 
                        NULL, 
                        OPEN_EXISTING, 
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                        NULL);
        if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            DWORD err=GetLastError();
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << i << " Didn't Fail o.o";
            CloseHandle(hCom);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
I also tried manually calling the function using

```
hCom = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1",
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                        0, 
                        NULL, 
                        OPEN_EXISTING, 
                        0, 
                        NULL);
```

switching \\.\COM1 with COMs 1-10 and keep getting the error 2 from GetLastError().

Comment: Your use of TCHAR and TEXT are hiding what's going on, and probably tripping you up. Check the "character set" setting in your project and decide whether you are going to use char (MBCS) or wchar_t (Unicode) and then stick with it. It looks like you a mixing the two.

Comment: I took out TEXT and tried working with only TCHAR (updated the code in the question) still error 2's which mean file not found I believe. The important variable szPort I believe is in the correct format or do you think some other part of the code could be the problem?

Comment: Found some old serial code here, only thing we have different is 0 for the second last param (flags & attributes) and forward slashes instead of backslashes. And using CString from MFC for the port name. Is the error 2 from GetLastError()?

Comment: Yes, I get error 2 from GetLastError() after COM1 through COM9. I also tried your suggestion of forward slashes but it didn't work and from what I found from looking around everyone used backslashes.

Comment: Yes the docs say forward or back are equivalent. Sorry I can't help more except to say to check which COM ports actually exist on your machine, or if they are mapped weirdly, etc.

Comment: Without knowing whether you are building for MBCS or Unicode we can't tell what you are doing. Why the cast to TCHAR*? Have you used to debugger to actually examine the szPort variable?

Comment: I don't know which I should build for in the first place and was following what I've researched multiple people use. szPort has the value 0x00a4fcac "\\\\.\\COM1", in the type section it says that it's char * tho, not sure if that's a problem. I am a bit new to this, should I be building for MBCS or Unicode? I'm using a laptop with Windows 8

Comment: Have you checked device manager for which ports your laptop has? And maybe hard-code to `CreateFile( "//./COM1", ...` for now, then COM2, etc. (depending on what device manager shows). Are you using an adapter or direct connect to the port?

Comment: I have 2 usb's connected but I am just looking to see which and how many COM ports are open and I can choose to use. I looked at my Device Manager though I am not sure which part refers to my Ports as there's no section called Ports, closest though is Universal Serial Bus controllers, would that be it (I don't see anywhere that says COM1, etc)?

Comment: The question "Which of my ports open" doesn't make sense. If you open serial port, it is opened. If you don't open serial port, it is not opened. Possibly you want to enumerate serial ports. Look at this: http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html

Comment: It turns out my programming was working fine. It was just that I did not have any COM ports installed. Thanks for the help everyone!